# IFRAME: How to check if an iframe is possible with a given website?

Tags: wordpress, http, iframe, https

Trying to use an "Iframe" and pull the data from a HTTPS site and place in an HTTP site.  Presently trying to do this in Wordpress with a plugin and not having any luck.  Just wondering is there a way to test to see if the website that I am pulling from allows this?

The code is currently there and you can see a blank space where the Iframe should be.

The site I am pulling from is:

https://www.halifax.ca/recreation/facilities-fields/field-conditions

The site where I am trying to put the Iframe is:

http://www.chscseniorwomen.com/field-conditions/

Any suggestions on this or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The site you are trying to pull sets

[`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

in the header. This means it will only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

You can e.g. check this via your browser's development tools:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Comment: The reason I thought it would work is this test site I used.  You can place the URL in question there in two locations.  The second location indicates there is no kill script.  Hence my thought process.

Comment: The page probably indeed does not run a "kill script". But the header check on your page already shows SAMEORIGIN policy for me.

Comment: Well this is frustrating!  So if by chance which pretty sure it won't happen.  If I could get them to change that what should it read and/or where would they change the code?  Ticks me off as last year they were running RSS feeds and was easy for me!

Comment: OK may give this a try. Thanks!  My only other option is an external link I guess.